Tuple question - Typescript
Hey guys i'm having trouble with syntax.
let's say in my program i've:
pub enum SomeEnum{

X,
Y(Pubkey, u64),
Z(otherEnum)
}

pub enum otherEnum{
A(u64),
B(u64),
...
}

In my fe/tests
if i want to pass the X it would be  -  { x: {} },
if i wanted to pass Y it would be - {y:[payee.publicKey, new BN(amount)] }
if i want to pass Z how it would be ?
trying stuff like this but it not working hmm
 { z: { A: new BN(amount) } } 


Syntax got me but at the end got the answer.
{ z: [{a: [new BN(amount)]}]} 

